# How to trigger vendors giving level-matched equipment in the Holodome and Claptrap, before Regolith Range?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

How to trigger vendors giving level-matched equipment in the Holodome and Claptrap, before Regolith Range?

Somehow I did it without entering Regolith Range, presumably by just getting to level 8?

I tried the dialogue of Zarpedeon provoking Deadlift to stop the Vault Hunters, and Claptrap's Consciousness after meeting SYS_ADMIN...

Then getting Grenade and Class Mods from Glitch Chests...

Neither changed the vendors' levels...

Is it really getting to Level 8? Or is it something else? I got the Out With A Bang LV5 Challenge, for instance.

Comment: They go up in level at certain points.  I know I had written those down in an answer to another question, but I don't remember which one.

Comment: @Powerlord - Well, you only have two posts relating to Pre-Sequel, according to Arqade? - https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:87105+[borderlands-pre-sequel]

Comment: I could try to dig out my lvl20 lawbringer and check that again, will bookmark your pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, seems like it's hitting LV 8. It's happened twice at that now.

And LV 10 unlocks class mods and cryo spikes for Nina's Item Of The Day, and Cryo Grenades for Marcus's Bullets. Or the Cryo element in general...

LV 12 gets Nova and Maylay shields Unlocked... And Corrosive? And purple Oz Kits?

LV 13 unlocks Blue-rarity Class Mods as Items of the Day, and unlocks Booster Shields?